# cassandra data modeling with denormalization

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling

I read [cassandra data modeling](https://www.datastax.com/blog/basic-rules-cassandra-data-modeling), everything is clear except that the denormalized data may change. How do I sync it?
What is the way for updating `email` when users email is changed from this example:

```
CREATE TABLE groups ( groupname text, username text, email text, age int, hash_prefix int, PRIMARY KEY ((groupname, hash_prefix), username) )
```

`groupname` is part of groups, the user from data model may not know any groups, so there is no way to update the email after the user changes.

Is the solution described below is appropriate?

Add to the user model a column `groups` (type `set<text>`)

If the user model has a primary key `username` then I can add some `DAOperUser(username)` with `updateName` and `addGroup` methods to the application.

For every `username` instantiate own object (through the factory), which will read state from `user` table on initializing. This way it will have `username` and `groups`, so changes can be considered as a `write batch` for both tables (`users` and `groups`).

Answer (score 0):

When inserting or updating data, you need to use BATCH statements to keep the data in sync between the two tables `users` and `groups`.

For example:

```
BEGIN BATCH
  INSERT INTO users (...) VALUES (...);
  INSERT INTO groups (...) VALUES (...);
APPLY BATCH;
```

If you're interested, there's a free tutorial on https://www.datastax.com/dev that explains the concepts in detail with hands-on exercise on a Cassandra cluster pre-installed running on the same browser tab -- [Atomicity and Batches](https://www.datastax.com/learn/cassandra-fundamentals/batches). Cheers!

Comment: I understand the concept of a BATCH statement . Problem is "no `groupname` when `username` updated". `Read-befor-write` is an anti-pattern due to Cassandra's distributed nature.